# Display DB fetched data using foreach loop in ajax request using jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, for-loop, foreach

**MY PHP response after ajax call**

```
echo json_encode(
    array(
        "id" => $id,
        "msg" => $msg,
        "data" => $result_data_came_from_foreach_loop
         )
     );
```

**Then the result is here in JSON format**

```
data: 
        1:"data1"
        2:"data2" 
        3:"data3" 
        4:"data4" 
        5: "
           "
           "
    id:"success"
    msg:"Data has been fetched Successfully"
```

**The problem is adding these data in html table**

```
limit = 20; // limit of already displayed rows
total = 50; // total table rows count in db
    dataType: 'json',
    success:function (res){
    if(res.id == "success"){
    for(var i=limit; i>total; i--){ // I think I misconfigured here
     console.log(res.data[i]);
   $('.table tr:last').after("<td>"+res.data[i]+"</td>");
    }
  }
}
```

*Nothing displayed in the HTML table please help?*

Comment: Not sure you wanner use `"<tb>"` but maybe `"<td>"`

Comment: Sorry, it was just the spelling error here only.

Comment: Your problem is here. `i>total` converting it, it says `20 > 50`

Answer (score 0):

`for(var i=limit; i>total; i--)`

Your loop variable is starting at limit i.e. 20, and the code is being executed while it is greater than total i.e. 50. So it's not being executed at all.

if you want to loop through res.data and stop either at the end, or at the limit, try this:

`for(var i = 0; i < res.data.length && i < limit; i++)`